# how to encrypt zip file with p7b certificate and sign it with p12

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, pkcs#12

I have a p7b file which includes the public key the goal is to encrypted a zip file with this public key and change the file to .zip.encrypted and then use a .p12 file to sign the content

**Questions**

Right now I'm trying to figure out how this works. Is this just pkcs#7 encryption or do I call it CMS Evelope? Since in the p7b file i only have a public rsa key how would I be able to encrypt a whole zip file with it? As far as I know you can only encrypt small bytes with RSA encryption. Is there somekind of bytestream that I can use to encrypt every single byte of a zip file by it self? Or do I generate somehow a AES key out of the public RSA key from the p7b file? Do I need to add the p7b certificate to my windows account to get access to the data inside?

**What I've tried**

I tried the .net recources and couldn't figure out how to get what I want, then I googled a lot found many examples how people encrypt a short string and tried to adapt but it was never working for me.

Now I'm using Bouncy Castle for c# and I think I was able to read the public key from my p7b file when I try to encrypt a normal short string, it seems to work. But when I use my zip file then I get an exception that my byte array is too big. The zip file I use for this test is only 3KB, the real files later will be up to ~200MB

So I guess the Way im using the p7b file aswell as bouncy castle for my problem is wrong.

**My Code**

```
 var p7bFilePath = @"key\Test.p7b";
 var text = @"zipfile";
 var bytesToEncrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(@"zip\test.zip");
 var certi = ReadCertificate(p7bFilePath);
 var encodedPublicKey = certi.GetPublicKey();
 var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
 encryptEngine.Init(true, encodedPublicKey);
 var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));

 Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since I asked this question before just deleted it and rewrote it a little with the hope somebody might help me. I think I came to the solution with the help of a collegue:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using System.IO;

namespace pkchwencrypting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var certificateData = File.ReadAllBytes("YOUR_p7b_FILE");
            var cert = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(certificateData);
            //I just wanted to know if I can see the publicKey somehow            
            //var publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();

            var store = new Pkcs12Store(File.OpenRead("YOUR_p12_File"), "test".ToCharArray());
            var privateKey = store.GetKey("THE_NAME_OF_KEY_YOU_WANT_TO_GET").Key;

            var signedDataGen = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
            signedDataGen.AddSigner(privateKey, cert, CmsSignedDataGenerator.EncryptionRsa, CmsSignedDataGenerator.DigestSha512);

            var zipContent = new CmsProcessableFile(new FileInfo("YOUR_DATA_FILE"));
            //For me a zip
            var signedData = signedDataGen.Generate(zipContent, true);

            var envDataGen = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
            envDataGen.AddKeyTransRecipient(cert);

            var sData = new CmsProcessableByteArray(signedData.GetEncoded());
            var enveloped = envDataGen.Generate(sData, CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.DesEde3Cbc);

            var dos = new DerOutputStream(File.OpenWrite("YOUR_DATA_FILE.zip.encrypted.sig)"));
            var bytesToWrite = enveloped.GetEncoded();
            dos.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
            dos.Flush();
            dos.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This might help somebody, maybe somebody can have a look at it, if this actually makes sense but it seems to do what it supposed to do.

Comment: This is pretty awesome and (nearly) exactly what I needed. Thanks. **Question**: Do you also have the code available to decrypt the encrypted file?

Comment: Sadly I dont, it was a project at my old workplace. But if i recall corectly, we just used some Bouncy Castle Java example and translated it to c#.